# Jersey & JSONArray: Java class org.json.JSONArray, and Java type class org.json.JSONArray, and MIME media type application/json was not found

Tags: java

```
    @GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response GetAll() throws JSONException{
    tblCategoryDao dao = new tblCategoryDao();
    List<tblcategory> categories= dao.getAllCategories();
    JSONArray JSONArray = new JSONArray(categories);
    return Response.status(200).entity(JSONArray).build();
}
```

The above is my code to return json of the list of categories.
I am using JSONArray to convert a list into json string.
I am getting the following error

```
  SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class org.json.JSONArray, and Java type class org.json.JSONArray, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

What is the actual problem?

Comment: What is your message body?

Comment: The message body will have a list of categories. Eg. {
    "categories":
    [{"id": "1", "name": "master"}, 
    {"id": "2", "name": "sub"}]
}

Comment: Did you add "com.sun.jersey" dependency?

Comment: yes i did. <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: Better to check jersey-bundle is downloaded in your repo or otherwise add jersey-bundle jar file to your project.

Comment: yes its downloaded. Its under Libraries->Maven dependencies->jersey-bundle-1.19.jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94569/discussion-between-markand-bhatt-and-jarachanthan-ratnakumar).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
return Response.status(200).entity(JSONArray.toString()).build();
```

You have to add `.toString()` to your entity data.